# 2x2 moderated mediation model - how to build the moderator?

Tags: spss, mediation, interaction

Hello friends of statistics,

first of all I want to excuse for my bad english skills. Nevertheless I need your help :)

My Design:

1. IV-1: social status of person,
2. IV-2: public vs. private shown behavior of the person,
3. Mediator: attribution about the motives of the person,
4. DV: assessment his behavior

I have to examine the relation between two independed variables, the mediator and the depended variable. My experimantal subjects have to judge about the behavior of a person, who has different social status (high/low) and different behavior type (behavior shown in public or private) and the overall assessment of the behavior (good/bad).

I have written 4 scenarios (i.e., low status/private, low status/public, high status/private, high status/public). SPSS shows me four manifestations (i.e., 1 = low status/private, 2 = low status/public,...)

**My question:**
I have no clue how to calculate and to build the moderator to use the moderated mediation in PROCESS (SPSS). My research design is: status is moderated by public/private, attribution-motives are the mediator.[image]
Do I have to calculate a new variable "moderator" with two manifestations (all people who got the scenario "low status/private" and "high status/private" get 0, and "low status/public" and "high status/public" get 1)? 
Do I have to calculate a new variable "status" with two manifestations (all who got scenario "low status/public&private" get 0, others get 1)?

Do I have to put these two variables in PROCESS with IV "status" and Moderator "moderator"? I'm not sure about the logic.

Thanks for your helping!

Comment: It sounds a little like you are asking for help with SPSS code, which would be off topic here. But I think you have an interesting statistical issue as well. You might want to edit to emphasize the statistical aspects. You may find that when you understand the underlying issues, you will be able to figure out SPSS for yourself.

Comment: Hello gung, thanks for responding. Yes, if someone has an idea how to build the moderator and the other variables I would solve this by my own.